# In spark how to handle bad rows? when writing to parquet

Tags: mongodb, dataframe, apache-spark

I am trying to connect to mongo db and write data to s3-parquet. But this fails --which i suspect is because of 1 bad row not complying to the schema (We scan 2M rows and derive the schema first and then use the schema to prepare the dataframe). Also, not enough hints are given by the exception pointing to the bad row --which makes things difficult.

Basically the mongo db is open to developers/ QA and its likely for badrow to enter via human error.

Is there a way to tell spark to skip such rows? or get spark get printed the bad-rows? How to handle such situation?

exception

```
com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast STRING into a ArrayType(StringType,true) (value: BsonString{value='ms_2'})
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.convertToDataType(MapFunctions.scala:214)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.$anonfun$documentToRow$1(MapFunctions.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.documentToRow(MapFunctions.scala:35)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.castToStructType(MapFunctions.scala:236)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.convertToDataType(MapFunctions.scala:208)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.$anonfun$documentToRow$1(MapFunctions.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.documentToRow(MapFunctions.scala:35)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MongoRelation.$anonfun$buildScan$5(MongoRelation.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1(SortExec.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1516)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```